# How to export response file from already installed Oracle database?

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, installation

I know that I can follow the steps of Oracle Universal Installer (OUI) and choose to save a response file at the end (summary step) to use it in further silent installation, but is there a way to export a response file from an already installed database to be used to silently install another database instance? I am trying to clone database initial parameters to a the newly created database but I did not save the response file from the old one's installation.

I am using Oracle 11gR2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not install a database. You install the database software. After that, you can create a new database from scratch or templates, or clone an existing one. These are 2 seperate tasks. Unfortunately Oracle allows to perform database software installation and database creation in a single OUI session, which casues a lot of confusion.

When you install the database software, the installer automatically generates a responsefile for that session and places it under `$ORACLE_HOME/inventory/response`, you can use that for repeating the installation.

When you create a database with DBCA, it offers you to save the scripts used for creating teh database, but it is optional and it is off by default. But you can create database templates from an existing database using DBCA:

[Creating Templates Using DBCA](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-30EAECFB-26D2-4D97-8450-75838B8229F4.htm)

To create templates:

> Start DBCA as described in "Starting DBCA". In the Database Operation
>   window, select Manage Templates and click Next. In the Template
>   Management window, select Create a database template and one of the
>   following options, and click Next. From an existing template
>
> Using an existing template, you can create a new template based on the
>   predefined template settings. You can add or change any template
>   settings such as initialization parameters, storage parameters, or
>   whether to use custom scripts.
>
> From an existing database (structure only)
>
> You can create a new template that contains structural information
>   from an existing database, including database options, tablespaces,
>   data files, and initialization parameters. User-defined schemas and
>   their data will not be part of the created template. The source
>   database can be either local or remote. Select this option when you
>   want the new database to be structurally similar to the source
>   database, but not contain the same data.
>
> From an existing database (structure as well as data)
>
> You can create a new template that has both the structural information
>   and physical data files of an existing database. Databases created
>   using such a template are identical to the source database.
>   User-defined schemas and their data will be part of the created
>   template. The source database must be local. Select this option when
>   you want a template from which you can create an exact replica of the
>   source database.
>
> When creating templates from existing databases, you can translate
>   file paths into Optimal Flexible Architecture (OFA) or maintain
>   existing file paths. OFA is a set of file naming and placement
>   guidelines for Oracle software and databases. Using OFA is recommended
>   if the target computer on which you plan to create a database using
>   the template has a different directory structure than computer on
>   which the template was defined. Standard file paths can be used if the
>   target computer has a directory structure that is similar to the
>   directory structure on the source computer.
>
> Follow the instructions in the DBCA guided workflow to create your
>   template.

Then you can create new databases using this template as well. For this however, you need a working database, which you do not have here: [How to refresh Oracle data dictionary to remove deleted tablespace and datafiles?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221105/how-to-refresh-oracle-data-dictionary-to-remove-deleted-tablespace-and-datafiles)

Comment: hahaha @ the last sentence.. you caught me :) thanks a lot, a very elaborative answer..